# How to create a link with a URL that routes to an action (MVC)

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I am working on my **MVConlineShop** project, this is what i made so far:
[image]

i have database of category and products in my `SQL server`, now i want to press any **category** to show the **products** in it, it will show them instead of the First Product and Second Product as shown in the image,any idea of how this is done please?i have checked `Ajax`, but will it do this for me?
and this is my `_Layout.cshtml`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <title>OnlineShop - MVCOnlineShop</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="~/Content/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="~/Content/css/shop-homepage.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">MVCOnlineShop</a>
            </div>
            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Services</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->
    </nav>
    <!-- Page Content -->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <p class="lead">Categories:</p>
                <div class="list-group">
                    @using MVCOnlineShop.Models;

 @{
    // stores the Session content in a var
    var Categories = Session["Categories"] as List<Category>;
}

@*Checks if the Session variable is correct*@
@if (Categories != null)
{
    <ul>
        @*For each category in the Session var, display the link*@
        @foreach (var Category in Categories)
        {
            <li>
                @Html.ActionLink(Category.CategoryName, "Browse", new { Category = Category.CategoryName })
            </li>
        }
    </ul>
}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <div class="row carousel-holder">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                                <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                                <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                                <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                            </ol>
                            <div class="carousel-inner">
                                <div class="item active">
                                    <img class="slide-image" src="http://placehold.it/800x300" alt="">
                                </div>
                                <div class="item">
                                    <img class="slide-image" src="http://placehold.it/800x300" alt="">
                                </div>
                                <div class="item">
                                    <img class="slide-image" src="http://placehold.it/800x300" alt="">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="prev">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
                            </a>
                            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="next">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4">
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/320x150" alt="">
                            <div class="caption">
                                <h4 class="pull-right">$24.99</h4>
                                <h4>
                                    <a href="#">First Product</a>
                                </h4>
                                <p>See more snippets like this online store item at <a target="_blank" href="http://www.bootsnipp.com">Bootsnipp - http://bootsnipp.com</a>.</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="ratings">
                                <p class="pull-right">15 reviews</p>
                                <p>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4">
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/320x150" alt="">
                            <div class="caption">
                                <h4 class="pull-right">$64.99</h4>
                                <h4>
                                    <a href="#">Second Product</a>
                                </h4>
                                <p>This is a short description. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="ratings">
                                <p class="pull-right">12 reviews</p>
                                <p>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4">
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/320x150" alt="">
                            <div class="caption">
                                <h4 class="pull-right">$74.99</h4>
                                <h4>
                                    <a href="#">Third Product</a>
                                </h4>
                                <p>This is a short description. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="ratings">
                                <p class="pull-right">31 reviews</p>
                                <p>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4">
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/320x150" alt="">
                            <div class="caption">
                                <h4 class="pull-right">$84.99</h4>
                                <h4>
                                    <a href="#">Fourth Product</a>
                                </h4>
                                <p>This is a short description. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="ratings">
                                <p class="pull-right">6 reviews</p>
                                <p>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4">
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/320x150" alt="">
                            <div class="caption">
                                <h4 class="pull-right">$94.99</h4>
                                <h4>
                                    <a href="#">Fifth Product</a>
                                </h4>
                                <p>This is a short description. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="ratings">
                                <p class="pull-right">18 reviews</p>
                                <p>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
    <div class="container">
        <hr>
        <!-- Footer -->
        <footer>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <p>Copyright &copy; My MVCOnlineShop Website 2017</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>
    </div>

    <div>
        @RenderBody()
    </div>

    <!-- /.container -->
    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="~/Scripts/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="~/Scripts/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: S.O. is not a place where people will do the work for you. You need to at least put some efforts in before asking for help, if after trying you have a problem then you can ask

Comment: i know , but can you please tell me the procedure on how to make it , and what steps should i do , and i will do them @Louis-RochTessier

Comment: Please go to the following link and study AjaxLink, as per best of my knowledge, that will do exactly what you are trying to achieve. http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/abhikumarvatsa/ajax-actionlink-and-html-actionlink-in-mvc/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create link with a URL that routes to an action in your Category/Product controller (depending on how you're breaking it up) with an id, slug, or something else that uniquely identifies the category.

You then use this identifier to either lookup the category or all products related to that category. Again, there's multiple ways you can go about this, so it just depends on what you want. If you look up the category, you'd want to eagerly-load related products at the same time using `Include`.

Then, you either return the category/list of products directly to the view or you may want to map to a view model(s) first. If you go the second route, you'd simply return your view model instead.

Answer (score 1):

The correct approach would be

1. create a partialview to load categories
2. create a partial view to load products
3. create a index view and load both in index
4. update products view on category click using ajax

Comment: FYI doing everything in layout is not the correct way. Layout is meant for header,footer and menu etc. which are common to application

Comment: yeah , i have classes and views and controllers , i know , but these categories are wrong to use them in _Layout.cshtml? @Krishna

Comment: Not like that if something changes between one page to another then you shouldn't keep in layout. Let's say your menu shows about,contact etc will you show categories in those pages ? that's why categories shouldn't be there

Comment: but i want to keep showing categories on the left , that's why i used it in _Layout.cshtml, this is correct right? @Krishna

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149132/discussion-between-krishna-and-ahmad).